# Access identically named class members of instances of different classes

Tags: c#, class, members

I have instances of class A and B, and both classes implement a member 'Text'. Is there a way to access member Text in a generic way?
I'm hoping for something analogous to the javascript way of simply saying:

```
instance['Text'] = value;
```

Note: these two classes unfortunately do not both implement the same interface with a Text member.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike javascript, C# is a static language and if both classes don't implement a common interface or base class you could use reflection to achieve the same goal.

```
instance.GetType().GetProperty("Text").SetValue(instance, "new value", null);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can't make A and B implement the same interface, then you need to use [reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7ykdhsy%28VS.71%29.aspx) to access any class member by name, something like this:

```
typeof(A).GetProperty("Text").GetValue(theInstance, null);
```

where `theInstance` would be an instance of the A class.

Comment: Thanks for naming the technique! You almost had best answer. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you should have single class with member "Text" which will be base for A and B. Probably it is not convinient, but it is more reliably and correct.
Try not to use reflection where you can do the same in other way.

Answer (score 0):

If you can make A and B implement the same interface

```
 interface ISomeGenericNameForAAndB
{
    string Text { get; }
}
class A :ISomeGenericNameForAAndB
{
    public string Text { get { return "some Text from A"; } }    
}
class B : ISomeGenericNameForAAndB
{
    public string Text { get { return "some Text from B"; } }
}

ISomeGenericNameForAAndB anAInstance = new A();
ISomeGenericNameForAAndB aBInstance = new B();
```